# How to increase JVM memory on Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

does someone knows how to increase the JVM on Tomcat 8? cause it changed from the previously version, I use to change it into the Tomcat/bin/catalina file in the following parameter:

```
set LOGGING_CONFIG=-Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties" -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M
```

but for Tomcat 8 is not working anymore.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: That doesn't look like the correct place for more command line parameters...

Answer (score 13):

You need to create file under Tomcat home \ bin directory

if windows then `setenv.bat`

and if linux/unix then `setenv.sh`

and write below memory configuration into file

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms512m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx8192m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

Please refer this link:

http://crunchify.com/how-to-change-jvm-heap-setting-xms-xmx-of-tomcat/

Comment: I see two times the same argument in the command line doing ps -aux| grep tomcat, which one is taken?  /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx4096M -Xms1024M -classpath ....

Comment: For people facing the same problem as @NiBE, and myself, the issue is setenv is appending to CATALINA_OPTS, and there are some already set (not sure where they came from).
I added this line at the beginning, and now it works properly.

export CATALINA_OPTS="-server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

This where the parameters I could see in the command line that where in use, besides the duplicate Xmx and Xms settings.

Comment: For issue reported by NiBE, please check whether you are using Systemd to start tomcat on RHEL, CentOS. I edited /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service script as I found JVM setting there and removed setenv.sh setting. Remember to do systemctl daemon-reload after changing that file.

Answer (score 0):

In tomcat bin/catalina.sh
add line

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms10G -Xmx10G -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"
```